# Fetching the user data from facebook

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I am developing website,where in there is registration format to log in to website.I have used facebook connect to fetch the facebook data,such as first name,last name etc.

It works fine when i use my email id to log in to facebook as i have created application.But when used different email id it pop ups saying "An error occurred please try again later".

Why so?Whats the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It works fine when i use my email id to log in to facebook as i have created application.But when used different email id it pop ups saying "An error occurred please try again later".

Is your app still in sandbox mode?

Btw.,

```
$session = $facebook->getSession();
```

that is a deprecated method. The current one is Facebook::getUser. Please update your PHP SDK version to the current one.

Comment: thank you so much..Its because of sandbox enabled it happened.Thank you very very much!!